# How to create a new properties to $node (or $user and so on)

Tags: 7

I would like to add a properties to the node object (or user, file, etc).

I know that I can use a field, but it could be useful to do this.

Which is the way?

Thanks,
Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In conjunction with the [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) module, you can use

[`hook_entity_property_info`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info/7)

> Allow modules to define metadata about entity properties.
>
> Modules providing properties for any entities defined in
>   hook_entity_info() can implement this hook to provide metadata about
>   this properties.

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_property_info
 */
function MODULE_entity_property_info() {
  $info = array();
  $properties = &$info['node']['properties'];

  $properties['nid'] = array(
    'label' => t("Content ID"), 
    'type' => 'integer', 
    'description' => t("The unique content ID."),
  );
  return $info;
}
```

See also [`entity_metadata_node_entity_property_info`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!modules!node.info.inc/function/entity_metadata_node_entity_property_info/7) for default node property definitions.